# How to access nginx server from outside using specific port

Tags: nginx, webserver

I'm trying to deploy a Flask app using nginx server.
This server is hosted on one of my computers with an ubuntu system and using my internet connexion.

I managed to deploy the app and access it via my local network but not with others network.
In order to do so, I tried to configure my box to allow remote access which is possible only through the port 4430.

Therefore I can pass the following test with success:
https://canyouseeme.org/

Then I changed the nginx configuration as follow: 
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/domain.app

```
server {
    listen 4430;
    listen [::]:4430;

    root /var/www/domain.app/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name domain.app www.domain.app;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
 }
```

The app is still not accessible from others network therefore I'm wondering
what manipulation should I do to get access to my app from others network ?

Thanks in advance for your help !